# Why does :nth-child not work as expected with a table having a caption?

Tags: html, css

`tr:nth-child` does not select the expected row when the table it applies to has a caption.

When a `section` has a `h2` and several `p` as children, `p:nth-child(2)` selects the first `p` after the `h2`, which is what is expected. However, when using `tr:nth-child(2)` on a `table` with several rows and a `caption` that naturally follows the opening table tag, the selector target the second `tr`, as if the `caption` did not exist.

```css
tr:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>This caption is the table's first child</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>First row</th>
    <td>1.2</td>
    <td>1.3</td>
    <td>1.4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Second row</th>
    <td>2.2</td>
    <td>2.3</td>
    <td>2.4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Third row</th>
    <td>3.2</td>
    <td>3.3</td>
    <td>3.4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<section>
  <h1>Title (h1)</h1>
  <p>First paragraph</p>
  <p>Second paragraph</p>
  <p>Third paragraph</p>
</section>
```

I expect the `tr:nth-child(2)` to select the first row since the 1st child of the table is the `caption`.

Comment: you can use ":nth-of-type(2){}" for element type of number

Comment: @Md.AbuSayed Thanks, that's true and would probably be more readable, but the question remains.

Comment: "nth-child" count all element index but ":nth-of-type()" count same type of index

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tr` elements cannot be child elements of a `table`

They must be child elements of a `tbody`, `thead`, or `tfoot` element.

`tbody` elements have *optional* start and end tags and are inserted implicitly if the author does not insert them explicitly.

The first `tr` is the first child of the `tbody` element, and is not a child of the `table` element at all.

[image: See this in the DOM inspector]

Comment: What you are saying is false. Currently, `<tr>` elements **can** be children of `<table>`s, as stated by the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr).

Comment: @MaximeLaunois _<table> (only if the table has no child <tbody> element, and even then only after any <caption>, <colgroup>, and <thead> elements); otherwise, the parent must be <thead>, <tbody> or <tfoot>_. I franky don't know which browser doesn't have `tbody` support?

Comment: @Vucko - The HTML parser adds the tbody element automatically as described in this answer. But the tbody element is not required for validity. i.e. If you construct the DOM by other means, adding the tr elements as chiildren of the table element, such as by using the XML parser or JS DOM methods, the result is still HTML5 valid.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.